# What does it mean that the semantics (of Haskell) are affected by the inferred types (of return type polymorphism)?

Tags: haskell, types, clojure, polymorphism, clojure-core.typed

[Here the commentator writes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22740268/15441):

> Finally, given enough macro magic this could be done... but likely for now less effort than implementing a Haskell-style type system atop Clojure. Typed Clojure could be a great model for this except it's been explicitly designed so that the semantics of Clojure cannot be affected by the inferred types. This is exactly what happens in return type polymorphism and so it's explicitly impossible in Typed Clojure.

My question is - **What does it mean that the semantics (of Haskell) are affected by the inferred types (of return type polymorphism)?**

Comment: If the semantics weren't affected then a type-correct program could run even if there were no type checker/inferencer. Since that's not the case, you literally cannot tell what a Haskell program will do without specifying the type *and how Haskell, the language, knows the type*. Though usually those are both the same mechanism and are  either the inferencer or a syntactic annotation.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Consider the `read` function, which has an (ad-hoc) polymorphic return value:

```
read :: (Read a) => String -> a
```

The implementation isn't so important. The only important part is that the implementation depends on the instance of `Read` chosen at compile time, and that inference can result in different types being chosen for the same call to `read`.

```
addFive :: Int -> Int
addFive x = x + 5

main :: IO ()
main = do
    print (addFive (read "11"))
    putStrLn (read "11")
```

There's a call to `read` with the same argument twice.  Haskell requires referential transparency, so it has to result in the same thing both times, right?  Well, not quite.  The inferred return type matters.  In the `print` line, the inferred return type is `Int`.  In the `putStrLn` line, the inferred return type is `String`. And because it's ad-hoc polymorphic, the semantics change with with the type variable.

The `print` line will print out 16.  The `putStrLn` line will crash, because `"11"` is not an input that `read` will successfully decode into a `String`.

And because the type variable appears only in the return type, there's no value of that type at the time the function is called. There's no way to dispatch on a value's type at runtime to figure out what instance of `Read` to use. The only way to figure it out is by knowing the type at compile time.  So Typed Clojure can't do this - it means semantics depend on compile-time types.

### Edits to address comment

I have no idea if it's supposed to impress you. But since your statement (2) is wrong in every way possible, it indicates a clear lack of foundations for even understanding this example. I think I have to go all the way back to what a type variable *means* in Haskell to explain this.

A type variable in Haskell represents an unknown but concrete type, chosen by the caller. The type `Read a => String -> a` does not mean the function chooses a type for its return value based on its input. It means that the function chooses how it will work based on the type it outputs.

Perhaps `read` was a bad example, in that its varying behaviors only look particularly different when it throws an exception due to bad input. And it's really easy for people with no experience with Haskell's type system to conflate that with something like a runtime casting exception, even though it's entirely different.

Your statement (2) is entirely wrong. The program does not crash because `read` returns an `Int` where the code expected a `String`, and something like a `ClassCastException` happens. The program crashes because `read` **chose a parser for parsing `String` literals based on its return type at compile time**, but the input it was given was not a valid `String` literal. (In contrast, `"\"11\""` is a valid `String` literal because it is quoted.)

The bolded part is the important part. The `read` function chooses what parser it's going to use at compile time based on the return type. That is both an extremely powerful technique, and something you cannot do with Typed Clojure.

Comment: Help me out here. You're saying that (1) the print line makes the read function return ints (2) that the second read line will also return an int (3) that this will crash at runtime not compile time (4) that this won't happen in Clojure core.typed. Um, forgive me,  am I supposed to be impressed by this? Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: @hawkeye You misunderstand pretty thoroughly. I suspect it's because of some foundational misunderstanding of what polymorphism in Haskell means. I've added to the answer to fill in some of those details.

Comment: @hawkeye (1) It's the type of `addFive` that means `read` returns an Int, and (2) it's the type of `putStrLn` that makes `read` return a String, _not_ an int. `read "11"` has to be a String, but `11` isn't a valid string - strings must be enclosed in `"`s - you need `read "\"11\""` - a String containing a String to read. (3) There are variants of `read` that wrap the result in a `Maybe` (so you don't crash at runtime) which are better for real life use - this is just a toy example to show that an entirely different `read` is used based on the return type needed.

Comment: @hawkeye You're not supposed to be impressed with the crash, you're supposed to understand that the semantics of `read` depend on the inferred types determined from context (at compile time, not runtime). `read` is (return type) polymorphic, so that the different inferred type of `read "11"` (`Int` in the first and `String` in the second case) causes different semantics to be used, returning `11::Int` in one case and rejecting the invalid String `11` in the second case.

Comment: It's worth emphasizing that `read` isn't a function, it's a family of related functions! However, `read :: String -> Int` is a literal function

Comment: Thanks for your patience. I got it running here: http://ideone.com/2C70kS Perhaps I didn't express myself very well. I guess I expected the compiler to pick this sort of thing up at compile-time.

Comment: @hawkeye It's just invalid input - the string `"11"` could have been user data. The problem is with `read`, not with polymorphism.

Answer (score 4):

One way to see this distinction is to examine System F. It's pretty similar to Haskell except that all polymorphism is explicitly introduced using "type lambdas". The typical notation is that type lambdas appear in type declarations as "forall" quantification (I'll write `\/`) and in values as "big lambdas" (I'll write `/\`).

So, for instance, `id` becomes

```
id :: \/ a . a -> a
id = /\ type -> \x -> x
```

So we have to explicitly pass the type instantiating the variable `a` in order to use `id`. You might see this used as

```
> id Int 3
3 :: Int
```

---

So, what does this have to do with return type polymorphism? Well, Haskell's type inferencer (the Hindley-Milner) system can be thought of as essentially living atop System F, automatically piping around the types. To do this it restricts a lot of the flexibility of System F, but we'll ignore that for now.

All you have to keep in mind is that the type inferencer figures out what the type variables ought to be instantiated as, all before runtime. Or, more clearly, at runtime *all type lambdas are eliminated*. This is what allows the compile-time/run-time phase distinction, what allows type erasure.

---

Haskell extends Hindley-Milner to allow a kind of bounded polymorphism. The type

```
\/ a . C a => a
```

says that the type lambda can be fulfilled only by types which are bounded by `C`. Haskell then solves equations about these bounds to determine the *right* types to insert wherever.

This is where we get return-type polymorphism. When we're inferencing the type which must have been passed to a particular type lambda we use information about both the inputs and outputs of a function

```
f :: a -> b
e :: a

f e :: b
```

if the return type of a function can constrain the type variables then it will. This will let the inferencer pick the right *System F* variant. Then, at runtime all of the type lambdas are gone and only the exact, type-free code which matches the return type demanded remains.

Comment: Just for clarification - as I understand it in system F - there are type lambdas and value lambdas. The type lambdas run at compile-time (and are eliminated before runtime) and at runtime the value lambdas run. Is that correct?
If so - can we consider the compile-time part of a macro similar to a type lambda?

Comment: Macros could implement them (they have control over the phases) but they only actually *do* implement them if the macros are actually programming a type system. I imagine this is how Typed Clojure operates.