# Why do Haskell inferred types in return type polymorphism lead to runtime errors?

Tags: haskell, clojure, polymorphism

The reason I'd choose to use Haskell is because of its [rich type system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haskell_features). This gives me more information at compile-time about my program, helping me have confidence that it is sound.

In addition, it would appear that Haskell is an optimal language in which to approach the [expression problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_problem), as [Haskell typeclasses can dispatch on return type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22040115/what-are-the-reasons-that-protocols-and-multimethods-in-clojure-are-less-powerfu). (In contrast to Clojure protocols - which can only dispatch on first argument).

When I explore a Haskell polymorphic return value function like `read`:

```
read :: (Read a) => String -> a
```

with the following program:

```
addFive :: Int -> Int
addFive x = x + 5

main :: IO ()
main = do
    print (addFive (read "11"))
    putStrLn (read "11")
```

I get [the following result](https://ideone.com/O0F6Rm):

```
Runtime error
...
prog: Prelude.read: no parse
```

So I appear to be getting a runtime error in a language with a superior type system.

Contrast this with the equivalent code in Clojure:

```
(defn add-five [x] (+ 5 x))

(println (add-five (read-string "11")))
(println (read-string "11"))
```

This gives [the following result](http://ideone.com/6KSvct):

```
16
11
```

My question is **Why do Haskell inferred types in return type polymorphism lead to runtime errors?** Shouldn't it pick them up at compile-time?

Comment: This is closely related to your previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23282921/what-does-it-mean-that-the-semantics-of-haskell-are-affected-by-the-inferred-t

Comment: Briefly (not enough time to write a full answer): because trying to read `"11"` as a string fails.  The problem has nothing to do with types *per se*, it's just that `(read :: String -> String) "11"` will crash; the format of strings for reading is that of literal Haskell strings, *e.g.* `"\"11\""`.

Comment: @Cirdec And I believe this question is answered in that question.

Comment: Thanks Antal - could you expand on that? (in an answer?)

Comment: Sorry Antal - when I try that myself I still get the same error: https://ideone.com/udjgGz

Comment: @hawkeye You should not change the argument of that first `read`, only the second `read`.

Comment: Got it https://ideone.com/oEgJmF

Comment: Those code fragments are not equivalent. Go back and put `print` in both places of your Haskell code and you'll get your desired compile-time error (type ambiguity). As it is, you are forcing Haskell to parse a string where there is none. Clojure is parsing a number and printing back the representation of that number.

Comment: As I said in my answer, you need to back *way* up.  Your questions continue to indicate a fundamental misunderstanding of the difference between type errors and other errors.

Comment: Thanks A. Webb - replicated here: https://ideone.com/zi0wcV

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of `read` is

```
(Read a) => String -> a
```

which implies it (compiler or interpreter, actually) will choose its return type according to the requirement of context.

Therefore, in `addFive (read "11")`, because `addFive` requires a `Int`, the type of `read` chosen by compiler will be `String -> Int`; in `putStrLn (read "11")`, it will be `String->String` because `putStrLn` requires a `String`.

And this choice happens at compile time, which means after compilation, your program sort of equals

```
main = do
    print (addFive (readInt "11"))
    putStrLn (readString "11")
```

But this `readString` cannot parse its argument `"11"` as a string, so it crash at run time.

The fix of this problem is simple:

```
main = do
    print (addFive (read "11"))
    putStrLn (read "\"11\"")
```

Comment: Ok - does the return type polymorphism take precedence over the argument polymorphism dispatch?

Comment: @hawkeye I do not understand your question. Can you give some examples about this concern? Maybe in another question.

Comment: @hawkeye the problem is nothing to do with type polymorphism. The problem is like trying to parse "abc" as a decimal number. Compiler can't tell that "abc" won't parse as a number. In Haskell, `putStrLn (read "11")` expects `"11"` to be a representation of `String`, which always includes quotes. It is the inverse of `show`: `show "11"` is `['"','1','1','"']`, with the quotes, not just `['1','1']`. So `read ['1','1']` can't parse a `String`, and the suggestion is to parse `read ['"','1','1','"']`.

Comment: @hawkeye The mechanisms for all kinds of polymorphism are identical. They must all simultaneously and uniquely align else type checking fails.

Answer (score 5):

That runtime error has nothing to do with polymorphism, and everything to do with the fact that the string `"11"` can't be parsed as a list of characters by the `read` function.

Here are things that work. Note that `"11"` can, at runtime, be parsed as an `Int` and `"\"Some More String\""` can, at runtime, be parsed as a string.

```
print $ 5 + read "11"
print $ "Some string" ++ read "\"Some More String\""
```

Here are some things that don't work. They don't work because `"Not an integer"` can not be parsed as an `Int` and `"11"` can't be parsed as a string.

```
print $ 5 + read "Not an integer"
print $ "Some string" ++ read "11"
```

As was pointed out in the [answer to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23283911/414413), the type information has already been inferred at compile time. The `read` functions have already been selected. Imagine if we had two functions `readInt :: String -> Int` and `readString :: String -> String` that were provided for the `read` function for the `Read` instances for `Int` and `String` respectively. The compiler has already, at compile time, replaced the occurrences of `read` with the original respective functions:

```
print $ 5 + readInt "Not an integer"
print $ "Some string" ++ readString "11"
```

This must have happened at compile time precisely because type information is eliminated at compile time, as was explained in the answer to your previous question.

Answer (score 4):

A part of the issue here is that in Haskell one can define partial functions, i.e., functions which may fail on certain inputs. Examples are `read`, `head`, `tail`. Non-exhaustive pattern matching is the common cause of this partiality, others including `error`, `undefined`, and infinite recursion (even if in this case you do not get a runtime error, obviously).

In particular, `read` is a bit nasty since it requires you to ensure that the string can be parsed. This is usually harder than ensuring that a list is non empty, for instance. One should use a safer variant such as

```
readMaybe :: Read a => String -> Maybe a

main = do
  print $ readMaybe "11" :: Maybe Int     -- prints Just 11
  print $ readMaybe "11" :: Maybe String  -- prints Nothing
```

Another part of the issue is that polymorphic values (such as `read "11"`) are actually functions in disguise, since they depend on the type at which they are evaluated, as seen in the example above. The monomorphism restriction is an attempt to make them behave more as non-functions: it forces the compiler to find a single type for all the uses of the polymorphic value. If this is possible, the polymorphic value is evaluated only at that type, and the result can be shared in all the uses. Otherwise, you get a type error, even if the code would have been typeable without the restriction.

For example, the following code

```
main = do
  let x = readMaybe "11"
  print $ x :: Maybe Int
  print $ x :: Maybe Int
```

parses `11` once if the monomorphism restriction is on, and twice if it is off (unless the compiler is smart enough to do some optimization). By comparison,

```
main = do
  let x = readMaybe "11"
  print $ x :: Maybe Int
  print $ x :: Maybe String
```

raises a compile-time type error if the monomorphism restriction is on, and compiles and runs just fine if it is off (printing "Just 11" and "Nothing").

So, there is no clear winner between enabling and disabling the restriction.

Comment: +1 for partial functions being the root cause of runtime errors.